# How to use Jena with Maven

Tags: java, maven, semantics, jena

I want to develop a web application which makes it possible to browse an ontology.

Can somebody give me a hint or an example how to use jena in maven?

Comment: But the website provides full details on how to use it with Maven: http://incubator.apache.org/jena/download/maven.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All jena releases are mirrored by central repo, so to use jena you need to add it to dependencies in your pom.xml.

[Here are the artifacts from maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.jena%22).

Answer (score 1):

See also:

- http://incubator.apache.org/jena/download/maven.html
- http://incubator.apache.org/jena/getting_involved/index.html

This is, for example, how to add a dependency on Apache Jena's TDB storage layer (i.e. jena-tdb) (which depends on jena-core and jena-arq):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```